# Apache Jackrabbit webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, jackrabbit, jcr

I would like to know if there is a (third party) webapp for apache jackrabbit, which I can use to browse and move/delete/edit the documents on my jackrabbit server.

I know there is the [web interface](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/standalone-server.html#StandaloneServer-Webinterface) created by the jackrabbit team, but that's just too standard.

I could write my own webapp, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People of Day Software (which work on a JCR implementation), have a [JCR explorer roundup blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20111126212405/http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/07/jcrtools.html) linking some alternatives.

Comment: Looks promising. I will check it later on :)

Comment: Alas, link dead.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett I switched to Internet Wayback Machine

Answer (score 1):

What definitively works with Jackrabbit 2.0 is [Torimiro](http://www.subshell.com/en/toromiro/index.html). But it is not free. Works for one month for free.

Answer (score 0):

This one was very nice when I used it a couple of years ago . . .

http://kenai.com/projects/jcrmanager

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the Jackrabbit Explorer. It is developed by priocept group. You can download the war from [here](http://code.google.com/p/jackrabbitexplorer/).